# Store encryption key safely on Android

Tags: android, security, encryption

I have an app which has about 150 videos. The app needs to run offline and as the resources and assets folders can be can be accessed so I have encrypted the video so now the problem of hiding the videos is changed to the problem of hiding my key. Now the key has to be in the code to decrypt the videos or to play videos using libraries like [libmedia](http://libeasy.alwaysdata.net). I can't even think of a way because the key has to be somewhere in the code to decrypt it so what is the best practice to go about it?

I know security is just an illusion and nothing is 100% secure but Android shouldn't be that easy to crack.. we are in 2015!

Comment: We are in 2015, but as long as you cannot run your code on a fully protected device, you cannot expect to implement a fully secure DRM scheme. You can encrypt your encryption key with a randomly generated one and store that in an Android key store, possibly.